# Place Photo from URL as a Navigation Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, alamofire, uibarbuttonitem

So far I have been trying to achieve the left bar button item you can see in the following picture:

[image]

I have not coded in the style yet but simply the basic code for getting the profile picture. Here it is:

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
var profilePicture: UIImageView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //left bar button item setup

    if let profileURL = self.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString {
        let profilePictureUrl = NSURL(string: profileURL)
        profilePicture?.af_setImage(withURL: profilePictureUrl as! URL)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: profilePicture?.image, landscapeImagePhone: nil, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(revealBackClicked))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }


}
```

I am retrieving my photo from firebase using the following function:

```
self.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString
```

I am receiving a url as I tested it by printing it in my output. However, I think the problem is when I set the image in the profilePicture variable because when i print that out I receive nil.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `photoURL` is already a `URL`. Why get its `absoluteString`, create an `NSURL` (don't use in Swift 3), and then cast to `URL`? That's 3 wasted steps.

Comment: Because it has an expected return type of a string.

Comment: What has an expected return type of a string? Just do: `if let profileURL = self.user?.photoURL? { profilePicture?.af_setImage(withURL: profileURL) ...` No need for all of the needless conversions and casts.

Comment: okay so I did what you said and it still does not work

Comment: I never said it would fix your issue. I posted it as a comment to show you a better way to write your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are trying to set an image to UIBarButtonItem while still downloading the image. You should download the image and then set the image to UIBarButtonItem.

```
let profilePictureUrl = NSURL(string: profileURL)

let downloader = ImageDownloader()
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: profilePictureUrl)

downloader.download(urlRequest) { response in
    if let image = response.result.value {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, landscapeImagePhone: nil, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(revealBackClicked))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, your soultion did not work. The image still does not load

Comment: @RohanVasishth, perhaps because you're not keeping a strong reference to the downloader? See the alamofire docs:
`Make sure to keep a strong reference to the ImageDownloader instance, otherwise the completion closure will not be called because the downloader reference will go out of scope before the completion closure can be called.`

Answer (score 1):

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let profilePictureURL = self.user?.photoURL

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: profilePictureURL!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
            button.setImage(UIImage(data: data!), for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
            button.clipsToBounds = true
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserGroupsMainViewController.profileButtonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

            let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

        }
    }

}

func profileButtonPressed() {

    print("Show Profile")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift & Nuke**

> Inserting image to the button with Nuke for UIBarButtonItem.

with the help of *[ImagePipeline](https://kean.blog/nuke/guides/image-pipeline)* we can easily get the image and use it where ever we want to.

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://....") else { return }
    ImagePipeline.shared.loadImage(with: url) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let button = UIButton()
                button.setImage(data.image, for: .normal)
                button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.height/2
                button.clipsToBounds = true
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
                button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
                
                let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
            }
            break
        case .failure:
            break
        }
    }
```